# How to get html element in web browser without an id

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, getelementbyid

I have a web browser and i tried clicking a button automatically once, however it only constantly refreshes the website.

HTML Element:

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Ich akzeptiere die Nutzungsbedingungen" class="button" onclick="submitAction();" style="width: 430px; height: 30px;" />
```

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(Adress);

var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("name");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.GetAttribute("name") == "Submit")
    {

        //link.InvokeMember("Click");

    }
}
```

Comment: Try `GetElementsByTagName("input");` instead of `name`

Answer (score 0):

As Rafal mentioned try `GetElementsByTagName("input");`
GetElementsByTagName function works on tags (div, li, input, img, a ...) and "input" is a tag here.

"name" in your case is an attribute.

Link to fiddle page: https://jsfiddle.net/hytL3619/